# Render two format json in Rails controller for Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, controller

On the client controller, within the Index we have the following code which loads a datatable via AJAX:

For Datatable:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { }
  format.js { }
  format.json {
    render json: TrainingProvider::ClientDatatable.new(params, view_context: view_context, current_provider: current_provider)
      }
end
```

Within the same controller, we also need to include another render json for a dropdown that loads client data on a separate page. And the working code for that is:

For Client Dropdown:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { }
  format.js { }
  format.json {
    render json: {
      data: @clients.map{ |client| { id: client.id, text: client.name }},
      total_count: @clients.count,
      items_per_page: items_per_page,
      search_query: params[:q]
     }
  }
end
```

How can I render both (Datatable and Dropdown) json within the Index for the Client Controller? How can I combine these two render json to one?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Tried to update the controller as mentioned by Masa, however, I am stuck on being able to add the params to the following code on the view page:

```
= f.select :clients_ids, [], {}, class: 'form-control remote-select feature-qr-code-generator', id: 'provider-clients-dropdown', data: { 'taggable': false, 'ajax-url': training_provider_clients_path(current_provider, format: :json), 'trainee-search-url': filtered_trainees_training_provider_qr_codes_path(current_provider, format: :json) }, style: 'width:100%;'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "both"? Please clarify it. If your controller must handle two separate cases, you can simply do `render json: ((MY_CONDITION) ? Training... : {data: ...})`

Comment: We have a dropdown on a QR Code page that pulls all Clients and is loaded via AJAX. This has been working fine until...

We have refactored our datatables to load via AJAX as well.

So the Client Controller is looking for the format.json with different code.

Is there a easy wasy to combine the top render json and the bottom one provided above?

Comment: Send a parameter, i.e `params[:dropdown]` and use it as a condition.

Comment: @Nav In Stackoverflow, the commenting facility is NOT meant be for answering questions in general. Instead, you are advised to edit your original question to improve it. Then, more people will be hopefully keen to answer your questions.

Comment: @MasaSakano thanks, new here and appreciate the guidance. I've updated the question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I can think that there are two strategies. One is to write a conditional statement, using `params[:dropdown]` or something, which should be specified by the sender.

```rb
render json: (
  params[:dropdown] ?  ## or whatever condition you set and give
  { data: @clients.map{ |client| { id: client.id, text: client.name }},
      ## YourCode
  } :
  TrainingProvider::ClientDatatable.new(
      ## YourCode
  )
)
```

The other way is to split the controller into two according to the two tasks.
I think it is usually a better design in Rails; that is, each Controller does no more than 7 methods of CRUD. See the excellent article "[How DHH Organizes His Rails Controllers](http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/)" (nb., DHH is Rail's founder).

If the Controllers are written separately, there will be no issue to "*combine two algorithms*".

---

Or, what you meant may be different from the answers above? If you mean that the Controller must **always** return a "*combined JSON*", then you can just merge the two Hashes before converting it to JSON as:

```rb
h1 = TrainingProvider::ClientDatatable.new(YourCode)
h2 = {data: @clients.map{ |client| { id: client.id, text: client.name }}, YourCode}
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: h1.merge(h2)
  }
end
```

providing that `params[:q]` etc is always valid and that `TrainingProvider...` returns a Hash.

Comment: Thanks @Masa, how would I include the params[:dropdown] in the following view page:

= f.select :clients_ids, [], {}, class: 'form-control remote-select feature-qr-code-generator', id: 'provider-clients-dropdown', data: { 'taggable': false, 'ajax-url': training_provider_clients_path(current_provider, format: :json), 'trainee-search-url': filtered_trainees_training_provider_qr_codes_path(current_provider, format: :json) }, style: 'width:100%;'

Comment: Again, please edit the original question in a way any readers would understand the point (especially when you include a substantial amount of code). Then, here, you can comment like "I don't know how to blah-blah, and so I edited the question.", which would invoke a notification to me.

Comment: Thanks again for feedback. Updated the original question.

Comment: To pass params should be a job by your JavaScript code that handles the AJAX.